# Select max value for two columns and get id of each row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, max

I have a table called products, that have columns `id, name, price and quantity`

The table has data as below.

```
id | name | price | quantity
1  |  A   |  20   |   4
2  |  B   |  32   |   3
3  |  C   |  24   |   8
```

I want to get the `max()` of `price` and `quantity` with `id` of the product.

something like below. I don't know if its possible

```
id1 | max(price) | id2 | max(quantity)
2   |    32      |  3  |     8
```

`id1` is the `id` of product having `max price` and `id2` is the `id` of the product having `max quantity`.

I think this is not possible, but wanted to make sure.

Comment: It is possible .. just tell me one scenario where you have `max Price` value for multiple IDs?

Comment: @pratikgarg Its ok to have first/last 'id' in that case.

Comment: It is possible using self join. Try to use that.

Comment: It's an odd request, as the two results have nothing to do with each other !?!

Comment: @Strawberry yes exactly, it is not related, but I want to get such 6-7 max values from a table. and I don't want to query the same table 6-7 times. So It's better if there is somwthing, I can do with one query only.

Comment: I would recommend to use multiple querries. I think the querry that will get you the wanted result will be slower then to fire multiple small querries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below query to get the desired result as

```
id1 | max(price) | id2 | max(quantity)
2   |    32      |  3  |     8
```

Here quan is the table name.

```
select
  q1.id          id1,
  q1.price,
  q2.id          id2,
  q2.quantity
from quan q1,
  quan q2
where q1.price = (select max(price) from quan)
and q2.quantity = (select max(quantity) from quan);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this using simple join without using `having` clause. But not a best practice. I recommend you to use multiple queries.

```
SELECT T1.ID ID1, T1.PRICE , T2.ID ID2, T2.QUANTITY FROM PRODUCTS T1 , PRODUCTS T2
WHERE T1.PRICE = ( SELECT MAX(PRICE) FROM  PRODUCTS)
AND T2.QUANTITY = (SELECT MAX(QUANTITY) FROM PRODUCTS)
```

Comment: the ID value always will be from first row, It should be of the row having max value.